# Pass the Length of uncertain Stream to WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, stream

Is there any way to pass the Length of uncertain Stream to WCF Service?

**Unsertain Stream** means the stream of

- The stream provides its length only after process and writing the data.

e.g. **GZipStream**

### Background

I'm making a WCF Service receiving **multiple** Streams from client.

As WCF Streaming only allows one stream in the message, I decided to concatenate all streams into one stream and divide it in server code.

The streams client provides will contains variable kinds of stream like `FileStream`, `MemoryStream`with data from DataTable serialization and

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var concatStream = new ConcatenatedStream(fileStream, memoryStream))
{
    client.UploadStreams(concatStream);
}
```

`ConcatenatedStream` is a Stream implementation suggested in [c# - How do I concatenate two System.Io.Stream instances into one? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879152/how-do-i-concatenate-two-system-io-stream-instances-into-one).

In server side, Length of each Streams will be needed to divide single stream to multiple streams.

As I want to save memory in client side, I decided to use **PullStream**.

**PullStream** will `Write` buffer on demand of `Read`.

But this causes a big problem. I cannot get Length of PullStream before starting streaming.

Any helps will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: May be you can zip all this streams in one and unzip them on server?

Comment: Cause I used .NET 3.0, ``ZipArchiver`` can not be used. And zipping files to local folder requires some extra consumption of CPU and memory, doesn't it? But zipping is still my last options, when there is no other way.

Comment: you can use this library https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples#anchorMemory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make it simple:

1. If you have the length of a part of the stream on client before you start pushing it to server you can append a structure before the payload and read that structure on server. That is a standard data transfer template. Doing so i.e. appending a header before each payload you give your server a hint on how long the next part is going to be.
2. If you do not have the length of a part of the stream on client before you start pushing it to server, you are going to have to 'insert' the header inside the payload. That's not very intuitive and not that useful but it does work. I used such a thing when I had my data prepared asynchronously on client and the first buffers were ready before the length was known. In this scenario you are going to need a so called marker i.e. a set of bytes that could not be found anywhere in the stream but before the header.

   This scenario is the toughest of the 3 to implement when done for the first time. Buckle up. In order to do it right you should create an artificial structure of your stream. Such a structure is used for streaming video over network and called [Network Abstraction Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Abstraction_Layer) or NAL, read about it. It is also called stream format AnnexB from the h264 standard. You should abstract from the field in which the standard is described, the idea is very versatile.

   In short the payload is divided into parts, so called NAL Units or NALUs, each part has a byte sequence which marks it's start, then goes the type indicator and length of the current NALU, then follows the payload of the NALU. For your purposes you would need to implement NALUs of two types:

   - Main data payload
   - Metadata

   After you imagine how your stream should look like, you have to grip on the idea of "stream encoding". Those are fearsome words but do not worry. You just have to ensure that the byte sequence that is used to mark the start of the NALU is never met inside the payload of the NALU. In order to achieve that you are going to implement some replacement tactic. [Browse for samples.](http://www.programmershare.com/1405589/)

   When you are done thinking this through and before you dive into that, think twice about it. Might be the scenario 3 would fit you easier.

   In the case you are sure you will never have to process a part of the streamed data you can greatly simplify the scenario i.e. totally skip the stream encoding and implement something like this:

Client `Stream` principal code:

```
private byte[] mabytPayload;
private int mintCurrentPayloadPosition;

private int? mintTotalPayloadLength;
private bool mblnTotalPayloadLengthSent;

public int Read(byte[] iBuffer, int iStart, int iLength)
{
    if (mintTotalPayloadLength.HasValue && !mblnTotalPayloadLengthSent)
    {
        //1. Write the packet type (0)
        //3. Write the total stream length (4 bytes).
        ...
        mblnTotalPayloadLengthSent = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //1. Write the packet type (1)
        //2. Write the packet length (iLength - 1 for example, 1 byte is for
        //the type specification)
        //3. Write the payload packet.
        ...
    }
}

public void TotalStreamLengthSet(int iTotalStreamLength)
{
    mintTotalPayloadLength = iTotalStreamLength;
}
```

Server stream reader:

```
Public void WCFUploadCallback(Stream iUploadStream)
{
    while(!endOfStream)
    {
        //1. Read the packet type.
        if (normalPayload)
        {
            //2.a Read the payload packet length.
            //2.b Read the payload.
        }
        else
        {
            //2.c Read the total stream length.
        }
    }
}
```

4. In the scenario where your upload is no-stop and the metadata about the stream is ready on client long after the payload, that happens as well, you are going to need two channels i.e. one channel for payload stream and another channel with metadata where you server will answer to the client with another question like 'what did you just started sending me' or 'what have you sent me' and the client will explain itself in the next message.

If you are ready to stick to one of the scenarios, one could give you some further details and/or recommendations.

Comment: Thanks Zverev. Scenario 2 is what I seek. Could you explain how can I insert the header inside the payload? Just pass ``MessageHeader`` in ctor of Stream and write length in ``Read``?

Comment: @Daniel I extended the scenario 2 description.

Comment: @Daniel I would strongly recommend you to take a closer look at the scenario 3, It will be much simpler for you to implement. You will just need to uniquely identify each payload say with a GUID which you create before starting to push data and memorize on cient, then you send an additional WCF request to your server each time you get the idea about the length, transfering the length of the known payload identified by the GUID. Two WCF channels, one for streaming payload, one for sending metadata. Very clear structure, very easy to grasp and support.

Comment: Thank you for scenario details. As you mentioned, this scenario is too tough for my service, and I decide to use scenario 3 instead. But scenario 2 gives me a new view of stream and I will take a look after my project as well :)

Comment: My first idea is almost same with your scenario 3. I just want to extend my service, so that every request can be done in single request. It seems nicer and cooler for me. But it is revealed that combining streams into single is not good idea, so I will  return to my first idea.

Comment: @Daniel I provided the simplified solution for stream data insertion. Have a look.